# How to get the attribute value of a Java Swing application object in SilkTest?

Tags: java, swing, silktest

Every Java Swing application has some attribute like **caption**, **priorLabel**, **className**, **accessibleName** and **name**. These are displayed in the **Locator Spy**; some with values and some without values.

My question is: The way we have **GetDomAttribute()** method available for web applications, do we have any such method available for Java Swing applications in SilkTest?

What if I want to get the aforementioned attribute values in a java swing application even if these attributes are not having any value (in such situation, I suppose, I will get an empty string).

Please suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest match for `GetDomAttribute()` would be the **dynamic property** support in Silk Test:

1. Use `GetPropertyList()` to get a list of properties available for a certain object.
2. Use a property name from that list with `GetProperty()`.
3. If that is not sufficient, you can also use **DynamicInvoke**, which is documented [here](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.borland.silktest.doc/STCLASSIC-A9164AAB-DYNAMICALLY-INVOKING-JAVA-METHODS.html) (also includes dynamic properties).